# Conditional tag for Woocommerce paged product category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, custom-taxonomy

I need to add some code to certain Woocommerce product category archies, but only to the first page, neer the paginated archives. Is there a conditional tag for that? I tried

```
if( is_product_category( array( 'category1', 'category' ) ) || !is_paged )
```

but it did not work.

Comment: did you get any errors? please refer these URLs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_paged/ and https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use woocommerce [`wc_get_loop_prop()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.4.1/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L211-L223) dedicated function with the `'is_paginated'` and/or `'current_page'` arguments as follow

```
if( is_product_category( array( 'category1', 'category' ) ) && ( ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_paginated' ) && wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' ) == 1 ) || ! wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_paginated' ) ) ) {
    // Here goes other code
}
```

Tested and works.